# Evolutionary theory applied to programming languages

Tags: reference-request, programming-languages, history, books

I'm looking for books applying evolutionary theory to the history of programming languages. Researching the topic I have found an interesting paper - [Modelling the Evolution of Programming Languages](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.04440.pdf) Any hints in this direction appreciated.

Comment: What research have you done?  Have you gone to Google Scholar and searched?  Have you looked at all the papers that cite that one paper?  Have you read the related work section of that paper to see if it mentions any other papers?  Why are you focused on books rather than papers?

Comment: I work in programming languages and imagine that there is very little – Silvia's paper (referenced in question) is the first I've seen. This is not a proof of non-existence.

Comment: Not really an answer, and it's definitely not a book, but Dennis Ritchie's [Chistory](http://cm.bell-labs.co/who/dmr/chist.html) might interest you.

Comment: what an intesting question!  of course to think in evolutionary terms you'd also have to address the environment.  I'd bet this is a classic case of mutual influence of environment and organisms.  new programming languages beget new demands (environments).